# Tikz arc arrow scaling problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I want the arrow to scale with the arc scale. See my example below. You will notice that the arrow looks fine as long as the arc radius is large.

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    pics/carc/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{
        code={
            \draw[pic actions] (#1:#3) arc(#1:#2:#3);
        }
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick] (4,2)  pic[red, -latex]{carc=10:290:0.2cm};
     \draw[thick] (8,2)  pic[red, -latex]{carc=10:290:1.2cm};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `bending` library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the `bending` library:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,bending}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    pics/carc/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{
        code={
            \draw[pic actions] (#1:#3) arc(#1:#2:#3);
        }
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick] (4,2)  pic[red, -latex]{carc=10:290:0.2cm};
     \draw[thick] (8,2)  pic[red, -latex]{carc=10:290:1.2cm};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But just one question- if I go below 0.2cm radius there is still the same problem. Why wouldn't bending correct this too?

Comment: @Jack 0.2cm is 2mm. Below this, do you really need an arc with an arrow so small? For such cases, perhaps better to use a decoration.

Comment: Well ideally yes, but I think I can make do with this! I was more just wondering why there would be a limit on the scale of the thing I am drawing, unless it has something to do with the printing hardware (on a computer you can always zoom to an appropriate scale right?)

Comment: @Jack As I mentioned in my previous comment (perhaps you didn't read the final part that I just added), a decoration could be used to treat those cases.