# Drawing a smooth, tapered path ending in an arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, decorations

I'm looking for a convenient way to draw a smooth, tapered path (i.e. a path of *variable* line width) ending in an arrowhead using TikZ — something like this (drawn in Inkscape):

[image]

One approach would be to use a custom *decoration* as described [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14283/stroke-with-variable-thickness/14295#14295) (from March 2011), but perhaps there are more straightforward approaches nowadays.

An idea that comes to mind is to draw a smooth path of *constant* line width and clip it with another path starting at the tail, going up to the start of the arrowhead. However, I just noticed that adding an arrowhead to a path actually changes the path itself (see code snippet and output below), which probably makes this approach a bit more complicated than I originally thought.

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=1mm, black!40, -{Stealth[length=10mm, width=6mm]}] (0,0) .. controls (2,-1) and (4,-1) .. (6,0);
\draw[line width=.2mm] (0,0) .. controls (2,-1) and (4,-1) .. (6,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

[Edit] Thanks to @Markus G.'s comment, the changed path issue is resolved (see below). How to proceed?

```
\usetikzlibrary{bending, arrows.meta}
```

[image]

Comment: Loading the `bending` library solves this issue. See also here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273201/118712

Comment: The calligraphy library can handle the tapering, and then you could add the arrow head separately.

Comment: Concerning your question of tapering the path, this question has apparently been around for a while, as you can see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14283/118712 There is possible solution given, but I couldn't make this work with an arrow head, but it may be a good starting point.

Comment: @MarkusG. : Here is a working arrow by Milo: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471213/8650 .

Comment: Could this question be a duplicate of: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471204/randomly-curved-arrows-in-tikz - I am not sure. -anyway there are some solutions, that might work here.

Comment: Your example is really what you are looking for in terms of geometry, i.e. are you looking for a path with at most one bent?

Comment: @MarkusG. That is indeed the approach I'm referring to in my question. Unfortunately, just as with Andrew Stacey's *calligraphy* package, adding a separate arrowhead to the path (which at that end has a larger line width) does not appear exactly trivial.

Comment: @hpekristiansen This looks promising — the variable line width is based on the method I'm referring to in my question, and they manage to attach an arrowhead to the resulting path. I'll look into it and report back!

Comment: @DanielN Good question! Although I'd be curious about how to pull this off for general paths, focusing on singly bent paths would suffice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

I propose a solution (or at least the beginning of a solution) based on @Alain Matthes's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14283/stroke-with-variable-thickness).  Looking at the image above, we see, on the left, a case when the solution works (a simple `to[]` operation) and a case when it doesn't (an `arc` operation).  The lower-right curve is the original curve from Alain's answer with `width factor = 1` (for reference).

I introduce a decoration that puts together Alain's and a `show path construction` that introduces the arrow tip.  There are three arguments:
the `width factor` and the colors, `start color` and `end color` (already present in the previous answer).

Note that the resulting curve is slightly longer; the yellow curve drawn over the lower-left curve in the image shows the original path.

*Remark 1.* You can modify the relationship between the widths of the curve and arrow at their meeting point by modifying the constants in the definitions of `\w` and `\d`.

*Remark 2.* I think Alain's decoration could be modified in a more intelligent way to produce the result you are looking for, but I don't know how (I don't know how to use `pgf` commands).

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

%%% Alain Matthes's decoration
\pgfkeys{/pgf/decoration/.cd,
  width factor/.store in =\wfactor,
  start color/.store in =\startcolor,
  end color/.store in =\endcolor
}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclaredecoration{width and color change}{initial}{
  \state{initial}[width=0pt, next state=line, persistent precomputation={%
    \pgfmathdivide{50}{\pgfdecoratedpathlength}%
    \let\increment=\pgfmathresult%
    \def\x{0}%
  }]{}
  \state{line}[width=.5pt, persistent postcomputation={%
    \pgfmathadd@{\x}{\increment}%
    \let\x=\pgfmathresult%
  }]{%
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\wfactor*\x/50*0.075pt+\pgflinewidth}%
    \pgfsetarrows{-}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{.75pt}{0pt}}%
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{\endcolor!\x!\startcolor}%
    \pgfusepath{stroke}%
  }
  \state{final}{%
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgflinewidth}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}%
    \color{\endcolor!\x!\startcolor}%
    \pgfusepath{stroke}% 
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  tmp/.style n args={3}{
    postaction={
      decoration={
        width and color change,
        width factor=#1,
        start color=#2,
        end color=#3
      }, decorate
    },
    preaction={
      decoration={
        show path construction,
        curveto code={
          \tikzmath{
            real \w, \d;
            \w = {#1*60};
            \d = {#1*90};
          }
          \draw[#3,
          arrows={-Stealth[width=\w pt, length=\d pt]}]
          (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) .. controls
          (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
          ..(\tikzinputsegmentlast) -- ([turn]0: \w pt);
        }
      }, decorate
    }
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[tmp={.4}{blue}{gray}] (0, 0) to[out=0, in=150] ++(6, 2);
  \draw[tmp={.4}{blue}{gray}] (0, -1) to[out=0, in=150] ++(6, 2);
  \draw[yellow, thin] (0, -1) to[out=0, in=150] ++(6, 2);

  \path[tmp={.4}{yellow}{red}] (14, -1) arc (0: 120: 4);
  \draw[line width=.4pt, decoration={width and color change,   
    width factor=1, start color=yellow, end color=red},
  decorate] (14, -3) arc (0:120:4cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```